# Options pattern with consumer object selecting the option for the dependency in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

I have a `IRemoteCaller` which is implemented by `HttpCaller` and it needs `HttpCallerOptions` for instantiating as like below,

```
public class HttpCaller : IRemoteCaller {
    private HttpCallerOptions _options;
    public HttpCaller(IOptions<HttpCallerOptions> options) {
        _options = options.Value;
    }
}
```

Now I have a service `RulesService` implementing `IRulesService` with the `RulesServiceOptions` and is dependent on `IRemoteCaller` as shown below,

```
public class RuleService : IRulesService {
private RulesServiceOptions _options;
private IRemoteCaller _svc;
public RulesService (IOptions<RulesServiceOptions> options, IRemoteCaller svc) {
    _options = options.Value;
    _svc = svc;
}
```

My startup will register my service and configure options as like below,

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.Configure<HttpCallerOptions>(o => o.SomeProps); //Default options
    services.AddTransient<IRemoteCaller, HttpCaller>();
    services.Configure<HttpcallerOptions>(
        o => o.RuleServiceSpecificHttpOptions); //Specific options to the RuleService
    services.Configure<RulesServiceOptions>(o => o.RuleServiceOptions);
    services.Configure<IRulesService, RuleService>();
}
```

Now I have two named options for `HttpCaller`, I want to inject the options specific to the `RuleService` when the `HttpCaller` instance is injected in `RuleService`. When I am not using it within `RuleService`, the `HttpCaller` instance should be configured for `Default` options.

How to achieve this?

Comment: I assume there is a method inside HttpCaller which utilizes the common options required by both RuleService and other services? Why not select the appropriate options inside the method, by passing in value which can let the method decides who is calling the method.

Comment: You can look for registering factory in service collection so based on the parameter, you can return the required `HttpCallerOptions`

Comment: @Ytan, the method in `HttpCaller` will be Post, Get, etc. which I will want to only allow payload to be passed in as parameter. Also I want the `System.Net.HttpClient` instance to be created within the constructor of the `HttpCaller` so that the methods are cleaner. @user1672994, do you have any reference?

Comment: Thanks @Steven, could you also add new tag **options-pattern** instead of **design-patterns** and **options** tags? Due to my score being low, it is not permitted. Thanks.